# Cannot insert 6500 lines of XML data into SQL Server 2005 where as lesser lines of 92 be able to insert

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, insert

I'm trying to insert XML data into a column of XML datatype SQL Server 2005. It was successful when the data in file is around 100 lines. If the data is large, my case is 6500 lines it fails to insert. There is no data inside but just empty column with all other columns updated successfully. Is that any specific I have to do to insert this large data.

Regards

Rajesh

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934430/size-limit-for-xml-datatype-in-sql-2005 and see if the limits or notes on Management Studio options apply.

Comment: Well, you need to ***SHOW US SOME CODE!*** How do you load the XML, how do you store it into SQL Server?